# Array to string conversion error when trying to upload sql file to amazon s3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-s3

On my local machine it worked fine, but now when I try to upload my dumped sql file to amazon I get this array to string conversion error. It says errorException in mimetype.

Here is my amazon upload code.Again it worked perfect on my MAMP.

```
 Storage::disk('s3')->put('MyBackups/2-29-15-11:49:18file.sql', file_get_contents('../storage/files/12-29-15-11:49:18file.sql'));
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the `MimeType.php` file and line number of the error you mentioned in your other post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Storage::put($directoryname . "/" . $filename, $contents, ['mimetype' => 'application/octet-stream']);
```

I'm not certain but I think it is trying to detect the MIME type of the SQL file but it is not clear why there is an error.  If you did a var_dump of the content by modifying MimeType.php you would know more.  Try my suggestion first otherwise it's going to be more work to debug what is happening...

Here is the source code of MimeType.php for anyone who is interested:

https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/blob/master/src/Util/MimeType.php

Comment: Okay I tried to add it in the file itself as well and it's not working. Don't know what triggered this problem. I will need to find a way to dump my database in a different file type I guess.

Comment: I would suggest inspecting the values being passed to MimeType.php, you could do a var_dump and debug_backtrace to pinpoint what is going on.  Wish it was more clear to find out the problem!

Comment: I have solved this horror problem. I just saved the file in sql.gz instead and it works fine now. So now I can sleep good at night knowing that my two app users willl never disappear. Thanks again for all your help.